# Python deepcopy

Tags: python, copy

Why the next code

```
import copy

class A:
    a = 0

def incA(b):
    a = copy.deepcopy(b)
    print((a.a, b.a))
    a.a = a.a + 1
    print((a.a, b.a))

a = A
incA(a)
print(a.a)
```

returns

```
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
1
```

I think it should be

```
(0,0)
(1,0)
0
```

Comment: `A.a` is a **class attribute**.

Comment: You are trying to copy a class object; that's not how `copy.deepcopy` works; it deals with *instances* of classes only.

Comment: I called function incA with parameter 'b' which is instance of class A.

Comment: No, you did not. `a = A` doesn't make an instance, just another reference. And even if you did, `A.a` is still a class attribute, not an instance attribute.

Comment: Use an `__init__` method on `A` to set instance attributes, and create actual instances with `a = A()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand it, in my first case 'a' was static variable.